# how can I make elements justify-content-between

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-lists

I want to separate between two elements one most right and the other most left
I try to use justify-content-between
but doesn't work I don't know why

HTML

```
<div class="post-left d-sm-flex justify-content-between">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="post-author">
                <div class="avatar avatar-online avatar-xs">
                    <a href="doctor-profile.html"><img src="assets/img/doctors/doctor-thumb-01.jpg" class="avatar-img rounded-circle" alt="Post Author">
                        <span>username</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="h4 "><i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt money"></i>400 $</li>                                                       
    </ul>
</div>
```

style

```
.post-left ul {

    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: inherit;
}

.post-left ul li {
    color: #15558d ;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    
}
```

Comment: please read here, you could find your solution :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: @NargesPms I read it already I use justify-content-between

Comment: Justify between should be on the list not the parent.

Comment: prefer adding these code in snippets, it'll be easier to solve :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Esra_a_shan just add `justify-content: space-between;` to your `.post-left ul` class, It will be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `justify-content: space-between;` to the `.post-left ul` , as below :

```css
.post-left ul {
    .
    .
    .

    justify-content: space-between;
}
```